# Adding a mysql table as custom Field in Smart Search(Joomla)

Tags: php, joomla2.5

Can anyone please guide me how to create a custom field (search filter) on joomla.
I want to create a custom filter from which i can select any particular table to search items in that table. Kindly refer to the screenshot i have attached.
I am a beginner to joomla & PHP.

I want to incorporate the search in the core joomla smart search or if there is any problem with that than i dont have any problem in having a dedicated page on the site.

I have 8-9 tables with 5-6K records for which i want to search the data. User will search some keywords and filter it with the table name present in mysql database. Search will use that particular table selected. Only particular users having access to that page will be using that search. At most 2-3 people will be having access to search.

What i am concerned is about the process of creating a custom field with drop down field of table in mysql DB. I tried searching but i didn't got any specific information. I have the knowledge on OOP methodologies but not much on MVC. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be done but will require a functional understanding of both OOP methodologies and MVC principles.

You can create a custom field to generate the drop down field of tables to search.

The next part depends on how you want to incorporate the feature into your website.  Do you want it to be part of the core Joomla search or have a dedicated view for it.

Another major programming obstacle is how to generate the table search queries in a way that doesn't require you to build out complicated and difficult to maintain query generation code for each table.  Otherwise any tables not explicitly codes for would not be part of search until you updated code.

I would edit your question with following information:

- where and how will user search
- does search need to list all tables and search all
- Is this something you want to expose to the public, or a tool for Admins.